# Global Resource Bundle in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, resourcebundle

Is it okay to store email in global resource bundle in Struts2 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of email you are talking about? moreover please remember, Resource bundles contain locale-specific objects. When your program needs a locale-specific resource, a String for example, your program can load it from the resource bundle that is appropriate for the current user's locale. In this way, you can write program code that is largely independent of the user's locale isolating most, if not all, of the locale-specific information in resource bundles.

if you want to store user email addresses i do not believe this is the good place to store them, you can either store them in the databases or any other such place.